# solution needed with a homework c# (cs7036)

Tags: c#, replit

I am trying to make a menu with different options on replit where the user can choose an option.
I am making the options on seperate files, so I later can call for the methods from those files instead of writing everything in the main file.
One of these menuoptions will have an option with a random generator which will generate a random string.
I created the method on another file, But when it gave me an error (7036) when i tried to call it to the main method.
I have pasted an example of the code here below, But you can also access and run the code on this link: https://replit.com/@AY2002/testc22#main.cs  Which will be easier to understand. I am a begginer and, Therefore seeking a simple answer.
Thank you!

> > 

```
    //MAIN replit FILE
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Namespace1 {
    // This is the main file where the menu is built. the menu is working fine. 

    // the menu have 4 options and an exit option, which will be divided into 4 different replit files and one of them will have a method that randomly generates a string. you can see the method when you scroll down near to the bottom of the main file.
 
    class Program {
        public static void Main (string[] args) 
        {
      
          string[] Menuchoises = new string [] {"Choise1","Choise2","Choise3","Choise4","Choise5"};
        
          int x = 0;
    
          while (true){
            Console.Clear();
        
            Console.WriteLine("welcome to menu");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
        
            if(x == 0) {
              Console.WriteLine(" " + Menuchoises[0] + "  {");
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[1]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[2]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[3]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[4]);
            }
            else if(x == 1) {
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[0]);
              Console.WriteLine(" " + Menuchoises[1] + "  {");
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[2]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[3]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[4]);
            }
            else if(x == 2) {
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[0]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[1]);
              Console.WriteLine(" " + Menuchoises[2] + "  {");
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[3]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[4]);
            }
            else if(x == 3) {
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[0]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[1]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[2]);
              Console.WriteLine(" " + Menuchoises[3] + "  {");
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[4]);
            }
            else if(x == 4) {
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[0]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[1]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[2]);
              Console.WriteLine(Menuchoises[3]);
              Console.WriteLine("\t" + Menuchoises[4] + "  {");
            }
    
          
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
        
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && x != Menuchoises.Length -1) {
              x++;
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && x>=1) {
              x--; 
            } else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) {
           
           switch (x) {  
            case 0:
              Menuchoise1();
              break;
            case 1:
              Menuchoise2();
              break;
            case 2: 
              Menuchoise3();
              break;
            case 3:
              Menuchoise4();
              break;
             case 4:
              Menuchoise5();
              break;
            }  
           }
          }
        }
    
         public static void Menuchoise1() {
         // Class2.second is the name of the second class which will be the method that will appear when you choose the 1st option in the menu. 
    // The second class is in the second file which you`ll see below the main file
// The CS 7036 error seems to be  appearing here
          Class2.second();
          Console.Clear(); 
          
          Console.ReadKey();
      }
       
       public static void Menuchoise2() {
         
         
         
        Console.Clear();
        
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
      public static void Menuchoise3() {
        Console.Clear();
    
        Console.ReadKey();
        
        
      }
      public static void Menuchoise4() {
       
        
        
        Console.Clear();
        
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
      public static void Menuchoise5() {
        
        Console.Clear();
      
        Console.WriteLine("press enter to exit the menu");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
        Environment.Exit(1);
          
      }
      
      }
    }
    
    // SECOND replit FILE 
    //this is the second file where i have the random value generator. 
    
    using System; 
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    namespace Namespace1 { 
    // class name of the second file
    public class Class2 {
    // the string[]args function that will later be put in the main file in order to use this method in the menu
    public static string second(string[] Random) {
      string[] RandomChoises = new string [4];
        // list on options which will be randomly generated
      RandomChoises[0] = "C1";
      RandomChoises[1] = "C2";
      RandomChoises[2] = "C3";
      RandomChoises[3] = "C4";
      RandomChoises[4] = "C5";
        
    for (int i = 0; i < RandomChoises.Length; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(RandomChoises[i]);
    }
      
      
    // the choises are randomly generated here

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int Randomanswer = rnd.Next(1,RandomChoises.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("You got the answer: " + RandomChoises[Randomanswer]);
      return Convert.ToString(Randomanswer);
    
        
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please, at least format your code properly.

Comment: *"But when it gave me an error"* - What is the exact and complete error, and which specific line of code produces the error?  Please provide information about the problem when asking a question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: Your class is named Class2 not 2Class and the second() function requires an argument...

Comment: You have specified that Class2.second takes a string array as parameter, but you are not passing any parameter. That is also what the text of CS 7036 tells you.

Comment: And if this is homework, your teacher will want aptly named identifiers, not `Namespace1`, `Class2` and `second`. And BTW it's choice, not choise.

Comment: Hi. The identifiers are there as examples. You`re right, they`re not properly named. And I apologize for the mistakes on the example.                                                                                  It gives an error when i am trying to call for the class 2 method from the second file to the main file. It must have something to do with the passing of the parameter, But i don`t know how to solve the problem.                                                                      How do i pass the parameter so that i can call for the method on the second file to the main file?

Comment: @Alperen022022 I think you should declare the function like this: `public static string second()`. In that function you don't use any parameters so I think you can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that the `second` method takes a parameter, but is not called with one. Since the parameter is not used it should be removed. Cleaning up the class a bit should give you something like:

```
public static class RandomHelpers{
    public static string GetRandomValue() {
    
        // use collection initializer
        string[] choices= new []{"C1","C2","C3","C4","C5"}
    
        // use foreach loop
        foreach(var choice in choices){
            Console.WriteLine(choice );
        }
      
        // You should probably not recreate the random object for each method call
        // But this should work fine for demonstration purposes
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // start from zero
        int randomIndex = rnd.Next(0,RandomChoises.Length);
        var randomValue = choices[randomIndex];

        // You should probably just return the random value,
        // and let the caller print it to console.
        Console.WriteLine("You got the answer: " + randomValue );
        
        // Either return the index as an int, or the value as a string
        // Do not convert numbers to strings unless you are writing to the console/file
        return randomValue ;
    }
}
```

This should work better. As you get more experience you should find better ways to split functionality into reusable methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the way you are defining the array in second.cs. You either need explicitly say how many elements your array will have, like this:

```
string[] RandomChoice = new string[5];
```

Or you can leave the number out and let the compiler infer it from the number of elements you put in the {}, like this:

```
string[] RandomChoises = new string[] { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5" };
```

You can read more details about declaring arrays in C# here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

After you fix that see JonasH answer about the method parameters in second().